# Can't send funny chars to SLIME

Tags: emacs, unicode, clojure, slime, swank-clojure

Although I set UTF-8 everywhere (in my `lein` project, the `slime-lisp` group customization, the Emacs buffer itself...), I keep getting this error when trying to run code such as `(def beta "β")`:

```
Coding system iso-latin-1-unix not suitable [...]
```

Happens only in Emacs, not when running `lein repl` from the command line, for instance.

What could be causing it? I'm using Ubuntu, if that makes any difference.

Comment: by the way...  Does *.clj* file have a character encoding specified that every *.clj* file have to use?  For example Google's Go language specs says that every source code file *must* be UTF-8 while Java doesn't specify anything (you can use UTF-8 or ISO-8859-1 or what you want for *.java* source code files).  What about *.clj* file?

Comment: The built-in `load-file` fn slurps anything so I don't think so...

Comment: All .clj files must be in UTF-8. This isn't documented anywhere (unfortunately), but it is hard-coded into the compiler: https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/3297866c23dd01a5b0db14ed836336d128972aac/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Compiler.java#L6912

Comment: @vemv: SLIME's default settings assumes Common Lisp, which has a different tradition of default encoding. If you use clojure-jack-in, it will automatically set the encoding to to utf-8-unix (since it knows you are using Clojure), but if you use "vanilla SLIME" you have to configure this yourself.

Comment: raek: cool, nice find! I don't use `clojure-jack-in` but plain `slime-connect` instead. this has the advantage of not creating a swank process each time. so I launch just one swank instance at OS startup, so connections take nothing rather than ~10 seconds (on my machine).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you should have following code in your `.emacs`:

```
(setq slime-net-coding-system 'utf-8-unix)
```

and following in your `project.clj` when you run `lein swank` (or setup `swank.encoding` Java system property to `utf-8`):

```
:encoding "utf-8"
```

Comment: `:encoding "utf-8"` made the difference for me; I was using `:jvm-opts ["-Dfile.encoding=utf-8"]` instead. Thank you!